# Remove items from list box by selecting a different item using excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

I apologise now as I am an absolute beginner (also my pictures and code haven't been generalised).

I have a drop down list box in Excel, populated by a range I selected whilst inside excel (ie right click the ActiveX Control after it has been placed and alter the properties). I would like it so that if certain items in the list are selected, other items are removed from the list so that they cannot be selected. Eg. there is a list A, B, and C, but upon a user selecting A, B disappears from the list.

[image]

My code is as follows. This first part codes for the drop down list

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim SelShp As Shape, ListShp As Shape, SelList As Variant, i As Integer

Set SelShp = Sheet8.Shapes(Application.Caller)
Set ListBx = Sheet8.ListBox1

If SelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Select Buffers" Then
    ListBx.Visible = True
    SelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Set Buffers"
Else
    ListBx.Visible = False
    SelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Select Buffers"
    For i = 0 To Sheet8.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Sheet8.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
           SelList = SelList & "; " & Sheet8.ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i
    If SelList <> "" Then
        Range("ListBox1Output") = Right(SelList, Len(SelList) - 1)
    Else
        Range("ListBox1Output") = ""
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

This second code is what is supposed to remove items from the list

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

If Sheet8.ListBox1.Selected(0) Then
    Sheet8.ListBox1.RemoveItem 1
End If

End Sub
```

The problem is, when I try it out I get a run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified error., and if I try and debug it highlights the 'Sheet8.ListBox1.RemoveItem 1', but I just don't know enough to know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, and I'm sorry if I'm missing something really simple.

---

**Edit:** I've been working on this since I posted, and have found some solutions, but run into other roadblocks.

My first problem was that the .RemoveItem method wasn't doing anything. Turns out if a ListBox is populated by using the .ListFillRange method, .RemoveItem won't work – a ListBox has to be populated by using .AddItem if I later want to .RemoveItem.

After I worked that out, I decided to try and do what I want with simpler data:

I have 2 Listboxes and I populate one of them with data. Upon selecting an item in ListBox1, that item is copied into ListBox2, and it is removed from ListBox1. Also, if certain items in ListBox1 are selected, other items are removed from the listbox so that they cannot be selected. Eg. there is a list A, B, and C, but upon a user selecting A, B disappears from the list.

I have got my code to the point where it works in certain situations. Unfortunately, the sequence of the items is important, and for some reason, for certain sequences of items, the code does not work as expected – eg my generalised items happen to be: Germany, India, France, USA, England. Upon selecting 'Germany', this item appears in ListBox2, it is removed from ListBox1, and also, 'France' is removed from ListBox1. This works fine, until the items are put in alphabetical order, at which point upon selecting 'Germany', this item appears in ListBox2, it is removed from ListBox1, 'France' is removed from ListBox1, AND India and USA are moved into ListBox2...?? It's as if once 'France' has been deleted, whatever was below it is selected and runs through the first 2 loops of the ListBox1_Change() sub for some reason. Interrupting it with a messagebox works for some reason, but I can't work out how to interrupt it without using the messagebox...

My code is as follows, with some comments on what I tried included in it.

Populate ListBox1 with items in random positions

```
Sub Populate_ListBox1()

'Clear LB1 before populating it
Sheet1.ListBox1.Clear
Sheet1.ListBox2.Clear

Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem "Germany"
Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem "India"
Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem "France"
Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem "USA"
Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem "England"

End Sub
```

Try to move selected ListBox1 items while changing what items are in ListBox1

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

'Variable Declaration
Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim jCnt As Integer
Dim kCnt As Integer

'Move Selected Item from Listbox1 to Listbox2
For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCnt)
    End If
Next

'Clear Selected Item from Listbox1
For iCnt = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
        Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCnt
        'Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = False 'Nope
        'Exit For
    End If
Next

'If Germany is in Listbox2, then remove France from LB1
For kCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox2.Column(0, kCnt) = "Germany" Then
        For jCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox1.Column(0, jCnt) = "France" Then
                Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem jCnt
                'Me.ListBox1.Locked = True 'Nope
                'Me.ListBox1.Enabled = False 'Nope
                'Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 'This crashes excel...
                'MsgBox "blah" 'For some reason this works >.<
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next jCnt
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate help with this, and would even take advice on using a different program that would work with excel (trying to alter items in a listbox based upon their index, which *changes*, rather than on their values is a nightmare)

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to achieve and may have a solution that could work for you (depending on how your worksheet is set up). Could you add a column as a marker of sorts? like column A is where your building your lists from, and column B is blank. You build your list off code referencing column B. Make a sub just for building your lists, so you can call on it whenever. Have something like `If column B is "" Then fill the list` (that being in a For loop that cycles down your list). Then after whatever action you can say if a list selection is selected, remove the marker in B

Comment: I reread your post and am a little more enlightened. If you want to build the list from a range, you can still do that. In either case though, you should check out **Collections**. That would most certainly point you in the right direction as to how you can make this easier on yourself.